# C# foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, foreach

I have a list which contains some values,
now I want to get all the data where ID is in the array with the values. The problem right now is that I only get 1 result while there are 13 integers in the array, so it doesn't loop.

This is my code: where messages is the array with integers.

```
 List<string> messageList = new List<string>();
 foreach (string i in messages)
 {  
     Recordset Persons = SDK.Create("R_PERSON", "", "PK_R_PERSON = "+i ,"" );
     if (Persons != null && Persons.RC > 0)
     {                   
         Persons.MoveFirst();

         do
         {
             string firstname = Persons.Fields["FIRSTNAME"].Value.ToString();
             string lastname = Persons.Fields["LASTNAME"].Value.ToString();

             personmessages.Add(firstname);
             personmessages.Add(lastname);

             PersoninboundSet.MoveNext();

         }
         while (!PersoninboundSet.EOF);
     }
     return personmessages;
 }


 messages.Add("Error, didn't work.");
 return messages;// null;
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure it is not SDKRecordset PersoninboundSet = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_PERSON", "", "PK_R_PERSON = "+i ,"" ); returning only one record, did step through it?

Comment: Your List contains Strings, NOT integers.

Comment: You return personmessages at the end of your first loop iteration.  This means it is not possible for the loop to ever continue past the first iteration.  I'm guessing this is not the behavior you're intending.

Comment: @ N4TKD Yes, that is the one that returns only 1 record. While list messages contains 13 records. So normally SDKRecordset PersoninboundSet = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_PERSON", "", "PK_R_PERSON = "+i ,"" ); should return 13 results too.

Comment: @DanBryant , where should I return the personmessages then?

Comment: @Marijke, I'm not sure I understand your logic, but I'm guessing you want it outside your loop where you currently have that error message.  The error message should probably be based on whether personmessages has the expected content rather than whether you arrive there.

Comment: @DanBryant , the error message is hit when my recordcount = 0, this is all above this part of the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to move the return outside the loop.

```
List<string> personmessages = new List<string>();
 foreach (string i in messages)
 {  
    //// Do stuff.
 }
 return personmessages;
```

Comment: I already got the solution, I forgot to close the if statement of a loop above this code. But thank you guys anyway and I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan mentioned above, when you call `return` in a function, you'll leave the function even if it isn't finished going through a loop. If you want to have a separate return for each iteration of the loop, I'd suggest storing each result in an array, then simply return the array when the loop has finished.

```
List<string> personmessages = new List<string>();
List[] messageArray = new List[messages.length()];
foreach (string i in messages)
{  
    SDKRecordset PersoninboundSet = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_PERSON", "", "PK_R_PERSON = "+i ,"" );
 if (PersoninboundSet != null && PersoninboundSet.RecordCount > 0)
 {

     PersoninboundSet.MoveFirst();

     do
     {
         string firstname = PersoninboundSet.Fields["FIRSTNAME"].Value.ToString();
         string lastname = PersoninboundSet.Fields["LASTNAME"].Value.ToString();

         personmessages.Add(firstname);
         personmessages.Add(lastname);

         PersoninboundSet.MoveNext();

     }
     while (!PersoninboundSet.EOF);
 }
 messageArray[i] =  personmessages;
}
return messageArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the order of your looping and checking mixed up. You want to `return personmessages` outside of the `foreach` loop.

Assuming you want to find each `messages`, and return an error if *any* `message` cannot be found, you'll want to move your error condition inside the `foreach` loop.

```
 List<string> personmessages = new List<string>();
 foreach (string i in messages)
 {  
     SDKRecordset PersoninboundSet = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_PERSON", "", "PK_R_PERSON = "+i ,"" );
     if (PersoninboundSet != null && PersoninboundSet.RecordCount > 0)
     {

         PersoninboundSet.MoveFirst();

         do
         {
             string firstname = PersoninboundSet.Fields["FIRSTNAME"].Value.ToString();
             string lastname = PersoninboundSet.Fields["LASTNAME"].Value.ToString();

             personmessages.Add(firstname);
             personmessages.Add(lastname);

             PersoninboundSet.MoveNext();

         }
         while (!PersoninboundSet.EOF);
     } 
     else 
     {
         // *this* i could not be found
         messages.Add("Error, didn't work.");
         return messages;// null;
     }
 }
 return personmessages; // after we've processed *all* messages
```

Alternatively, maybe you wanted to return an error if *no* `message` could be found. In that case, keep your error checking outside the loop, but check the `Count` to determine:

```
 List<string> personmessages = new List<string>();
 foreach (string i in messages)
 {  
     SDKRecordset PersoninboundSet = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_PERSON", "", "PK_R_PERSON = "+i ,"" );
     if (PersoninboundSet != null && PersoninboundSet.RecordCount > 0)
     {

         PersoninboundSet.MoveFirst();

         do
         {
             string firstname = PersoninboundSet.Fields["FIRSTNAME"].Value.ToString();
             string lastname = PersoninboundSet.Fields["LASTNAME"].Value.ToString();

             personmessages.Add(firstname);
             personmessages.Add(lastname);

             PersoninboundSet.MoveNext();

         }
         while (!PersoninboundSet.EOF);
     }
 }
 if (personmessages.Count == 0) 
 {
     // none found
     messages.Add("Error, didn't work.");
     return messages;// null;
 }      
 else
 {
     return personmessages; // after we've processed *all* messages
 }
```